# UtilSnips plugin installation with pathogen gvim (v7.x) issue

Tags: python, vim, plugins, pathogen, ultisnips

I'm having difficulty installing UltiSnips onto gvim using pathogen (on Windows 7).When I place the UltiSnips folder in vim73/bundle gvim subsequently won't open. When I remove UltiSnips gvim opens again as normal.

The version of gvim is 7.3.
The command

```
:echo has ("python")
```

returned '1'.
The command

```
:echo has ("python3")
```

returned '0'
Running the commands

```
:py import sys; print(sys.version) 

:py3 import sys; print(sys.version)
```

caused gvim to crash abruptly. I ran the :version command (see below) to obtain info about whether python was installed, and it appears to be. The vimrc is very minimial (see below).

I've tried running it with the line

```
let g:UltiSnipsUsePythonVersion = 2
```

and

```
let g:UltiSnipsUsePythonVersion = 3
```

Below are output of version command, and vimrc

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2010 17:59:02)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Included patches: 1-46
Compiled by Bram@KIBAALE
Big version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms 
+byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard 
+cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape 
+dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags 
+eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +gettext/dyn 
-hangul_input +iconv/dyn +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap 
+langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap
-lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape 
+multi_byte_ime/dyn +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg 
+ole -osfiletype +path_extra +perl/dyn +persistent_undo 
-postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn +python3/dyn 
+quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop 
+syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl/dyn 
-tgetent -termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar 
+user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra 
+viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows 
+writebackup -xfontset -xim -xterm_save +xpm_w32 
system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
2nd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim" 
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32   
-DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG   -DFEAT_XPM_W32   -DWINVER=0x0400 
-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400  /Fo.\ObjGOLYHTR/ /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT 
-DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_GUI_W32 -DDYNAMIC_ICONV 
-DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl83.dll\" 
-DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.3\" -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON 
-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 
-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python31.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL 
-DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl512.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY 
-DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=191 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby191.dll\" 
-DFEAT_BIG /Fd.\ObjGOLYHTR/ /Zi
Linking: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:windows /LTCG:STATUS
oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  
comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib gdi32.lib version.lib   
winspool.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib 
libcmt.lib oleaut32.lib  user32.lib      
/nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python31.lib   
e:\tcl\lib\tclstub83.lib WSock32.lib e:\xpm\lib\libXpm.lib /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug

====================================  

set nocompatible

execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

let g:UltiSnipsUsePythonVersion = 2

set laststatus=2
```

Advice appreciated,

GilFra

Answer (score 0):

Never mess with Vim's runtime files. Don't add, don't remove, don't change.

Third party and custom scripts must go into `$HOME/_vimfiles`.

Comment: Hi romaini, thanks for replying. As far as I can tell my actions are in line with the requirements in the help documentation for the plugin (lines: 77-111) [link] (https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt). Instructions for installation using pathogen are to place scripts in the /bundle folder (lines: 127-135). Thanks, GilFra

Comment: No. Your `bundle` directory should be there: `$HOME\_vimfiles\bundle`.

Comment: Hi romainl, thanks for putting me in the right direction. At least gvim is now opening.